# Adding files to WEB-INF folder using ANT

Tags: jakarta-ee, ant

I have the below task in my ant and it is copying all the files like jdbc.properties, applicationContext.xml outside WEB-INF folder. But what I need is the files to be placed under WEB-INF folder. How do I achieve this?

```
<war destfile="my.war" webxml="web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
   <classes dir="build/web/WEB-INF/classes"/>
   <fileset dir="web/WEB-INF"/>
   <lib dir="web/WEB-INF/lib"/>
   <zipfileset dir="web/images" prefix="images"/>
</war>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<fileset>`, use `<sipfileset>` it's just like `<fileset>` except you can declare a *prefix* parameter:

```
<war destfile="my.war" webxml="web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
    <classes dir="build/web/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <zipfileset dir="web/WEB-INF"
        prefix=WEB-INF"/>
    <lib dir="web/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    <zipfileset dir="web/images" prefix="images"/>
</war>
```

Or, since those files are already under a `WEB-INF` directory, you can specify a `<fileset>` to the `web` directory, and then specify only the `WEB-INF` directory underneath that:

```
<war destfile="my.war" webxml="web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
    <classes dir="build/web/WEB-INF/classes"/>
    <fileset dir="web">
        <include name="WEB-INF/**"/>
    </fileset>
    <lib dir="web/WEB-INF/lib"/>
    <zipfileset dir="web/images" prefix="images"/>
</war>
```